# How do you deal with the ' and \ characters in a polyline?

Tags: python-3.x, polyline

I have some encoded polylines. I want to use them in python code but they have some characters such as ' and \ . Hence I cannot use them as a string.

See this polyline:

```
qcnyFi{{oD?QIKRTRn@Zj@@VFVPb@VtBZbBHv@Fx@VjAJlABv@L`BRjAl@rBRrAVxCAt@LvA\\hCXnALjATlAXlATd@r@p@f@RLFZ\\NBN@^C`Ae@b@OXG\\CH@`@LxHbDNL|A|AX`@JTPfANn@LR^^`@Xf@Jd@AjAYb@QREb@CP@b@J\\PLJX^HPjAjDh@vAJTZd@~@dAlAfAhAlATL~Ab@TLPRNVvA|C|A`EbClH`GjP
```